# IOS8 UIButton highlight effect

Tags: uibutton, ios8, highlight

In IOS8, if you set an icon to a tabbaritem, when it is clicked, it will checked to blue color.
Just very sample:

```
FolderViewController* vcFolder = [[FolderViewController alloc] init];
[vcFolder setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"folder", @"") image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_folder.png"] tag:0]];
```

is it possible for do the same thing on uibutton with a custom image? 
I know i can override the uibutton and redraw the image with blue color and show it.
but is there any simple way just as simple as what we did on tabbar item?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
`-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state` method of `UIButton` and set the appropriate image for `UIControlStateSelected` state.

And when you press the button you should set the `selected` property of UIButton to true, to indicate that it's selected.

This should be it if I've understood your problem correctly.

Comment: thanks. but i didn't want to create another image. just like tabbaritem, we don't have to create 2 set of image for normal state and selected state